# Google App Engine + Google Cloud Storage Permission issue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've got a fairly old AppEngine (python) application that has been running for several years without issue.

I use task queues for move images into Google Cloud Storage.

My code is using the GCS client (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage) to do this and basically looks like:

```
# open the file and write to it using the gcs client
f = gcs.open(filename, 'w')
f.write(blob)
f.close()
```

NB: The filename includes the bucket so it's effectively '/[bucketname]/abc123'

When I "trace' the issue using the tools provided by the cloud console I can see that a 403 error is being thrown via URLFetch when it calls "storage.googleapis.com".

I've been through the process of adding IAM permissions to the bucket for the particular app-engine (xyz@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) service account. Have changed this account to be a "Storage Admin" but it doesn't seem to have made any difference. I've also added this role via the permissions on bucket itself.

So I'm not sure why it's not working...

Does anybody have an advice as to what I might be doing wrong? This all seems a bit confusing really.

Thanks for any help in advance,
Matt

Comment: You could try 'impersonating' your service account in a Cloud Shell session and uploading the file using gsutil. That way you can rule out any issue with the permissions associated with your service account. To do this download your credentials file from the Service Accounts screen in the Console. Then use the command
`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=path/to/my/credentials`
and then the gsutil command would be
`gsutil -D cp image.png gs://my_bucket_name`.
If necessary you can share the output here (but be very careful about posting any sensitive info that is outputted)

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. Will try that.